# Python's JSON module doesn't use __get__?

Tags: python, json

When I serialize a list of objects with a custom `__get__` method, `__get__` is not called and the raw (unprocessed by custom `__get__`) value from `__set__` is used. How does Python's `json` module iterate over an item?

Note: if I iterate over the list before serializing, the correct value returned by `__get__` is used.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: The `__get__` and `__set__` methods are used for the descriptor protocol, which doesn't seem to apply here. They should only be called when they're attributes of a class, and you're getting or setting those attributes on the class or an instance of it.

Comment: thats interesting, i thought that since `__set__` is called when assigning a value, `__get__` would always be called when retrieving.

Answer (score 1):

It checks whether the object is certain values, or isinstances of list, tuple, or dicts...

It provides a method for what to do if all this fails, and documents how to do this:

```
import simplejson
class IterEncoder(simplejson.JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, o):
    try:
      iterable = iter(o)
    except TypeError:
      pass
    else:
      return list(iterable)
    return simplejson.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

simplejson.dumps(YourObject,cls=IterEncoder)
```

Comment: actually, im already using a custom json encoder. its just being given  the raw value, and not the result of `__get__`. any ideas?

Comment: Could you post an example of the object you are trying to serialize? From the way it looks to me at the moment, if you're using an encoder like this one, then the iterated objects will be passed in the list `chunks` to `"".join(chunks)`.

Answer (score 0):

From the Python 3.1.2 documentation (re-formatted for viewing here but otherwise unedited):

```
json.dump(obj, fp, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True,
          allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None,
          default=None, **kw)
```

> *default(obj)* is a function that should return a serializable version of *obj* or raise *TypeError*. The default simply raises *TypeError*.

So your `__get__` function should be passed as `default=yourcustomjsonencoder.__get__` or something like that?  Just a thought.  I could be way off (and probably am), but it's an idea at least.